# Disable users to scroll up in tableView?

Tags: swift, uitableview

Similar to tinder, if a user goes down, I don't want them to be able to go back upwards. How do I do this?

I tried the code below, but it keeps running an error: Index out of range.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return userList.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableCell", for: indexPath) as! FeedTableViewCell
        

        cell.collectionView.delegate = self
        cell.collectionView.dataSource = self
        
        //reloading the tableview
        let artist: UserModel
        
        artist = self.userList[indexPath.row]
        
        cell.nameLabel.text = artist.name
        cell.passionLabel.text = artist.passion
        
        cell.collectionView.reloadData()
        
        if indexPath.row == 1 {
            userList.removeFirst()
        }

        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Refer below code,**

You need to store last scroll Content Offset of tableview, when user scroll down, refer scrollViewDidScroll method.

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var lastContentOffsetY:CGFloat = 0.0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.bounces = false
    self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "reuse")
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 50
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuse")
    
    return cell!
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    
    
    if(scrollView.contentOffset.y < self.lastContentOffsetY){
        self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:scrollView.contentOffset.x, y: self.lastContentOffsetY), animated: false)
    }else{
        self.lastContentOffsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    }
}
```